# Why incorrect value inside the closure when passing parameter to Laravel Eloquent when() method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a weird value for the parameter inside the closure when I pass this variable to **when()** method of Laravel Eloquent. Inside the closure, for `$user_id` I get `true` instead of `2`. What might be the reason for that?

```php
$user_id = 2;

$orders = Order::with('user')
    ->when(!empty($user_id), function ($query, $user_id) {
        dd($user_id); // <-------- HERE I get TRUE instead of "2" as value.
        $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->when(($filter == 'paymentreceived'), function ($query) {
        $query->paymentConfirmationReceived();
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument that is passed to the closure, callback, is the "value". The "value" is the first argument that you pass to `when`:

```
public function when($value = null, callable $callback = null, callable $default = null)
{
    ...
    return $callback($this, $value) ?? $this;
    ...
}
```

Since you are passing a boolean as the first argument to `when`, `$value`, you are getting `true` in your callback as the second argument. (It has to be `true` or this callback would not have been executed)

You would have to be passing `$user_id` as the first argument to `when` (the value you are checking) if you want it passed to the callback as an argument. Then, the second argument to the callback would be the value of `$user_id`.

```
...->when($user_id, function ($builder, $user_id) { ... })
```

Otherwise, you would have to inherit `$user_id` from the parent scope using the `use` construct (as demonstrated in the previous answer):

```
...->when(..., function ($builder) use ($user_id) { ... })
```

[PHP.net Manual - Anonymous Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) - **Example #3**

Answer (score 3):

Browse: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#123995

Use like this:

```php
$user_id = 2;

$orders = Order::with('user')
    ->when(!empty($user_id), function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })
    ->when(($filter == 'paymentreceived'), function ($query) {
        $query->paymentConfirmationReceived();
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```